# How to map a arabic character to english string using python

Tags: python, unicode, arabic

I am trying to read a file that has Arabic characters like, 'ع ' and map it to English string "AYN". I want to create such a mapping of all 28 Arabic alphabets to English string in Python 3.4. I am still a beginner in Python and do not have much clue how to start. The file that has Arabic character is coded in UTF8 format.

Comment: Dictionary. Search for it. It's the hashtable in python

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `unicodedata`;

(note: This is Python 3. In Python 2 use `u'ع'` instead)

```
In [1]: import unicodedata

In [2]: unicodedata.name('a')
Out[2]: 'LATIN SMALL LETTER A'

In [6]: unicodedata.name('ع')
Out[6]: 'ARABIC LETTER AIN'

In [7]: unicodedata.name('ع').split()[-1]
Out[7]: 'AIN'
```

The last line works fine with simple letters, but not with all Arabic symbols. E.g. ڥ is ARABIC LETTER FEH WITH THREE DOTS BELOW.

So you could use;

```
In [26]: unicodedata.name('ڥ').lower().split()[2]
Out[26]: 'feh'
```

or

```
In [28]: unicodedata.name('ڥ').lower()[14:]
Out[28]: 'feh with three dots below'
```

For identifying characters use something like this (Python 3) ;

```
c = 'ع'
id = unicodedata.name(c).lower()
if 'arabic letter' in id:
    print("{}: {}".format(c, id[14:].lower()))
```

This would produce;

```
ع: ain
```

I'm filtering for the string 'arabic letter' because the [arabic unicode block](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arabic_%28Unicode_block%29) has a lot of other symbols as well.

A complete dictionary can be made with:

```
arabicdict = {}
for n in range(0x600, 0x700):
    c = chr(n)
    try:
        id =  unicodedata.name(c).lower()
        if 'arabic letter' in id:
            arabicdict[c] = id[14:]
    except ValueError:
        pass
```

Comment: when I run your first example on windows DOS prompt, I get the following error,

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "arabic.py", line 5, in <module>
    print("{}: {}".format(c, id[14:].lower()))
  File "C:\Python34\lib\encodings\cp437.py", line 19, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_map)[0]
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u0639' in position
0: character maps to <undefined>

Comment: @Naseem That is an encoding issue. My terminal uses UTF-8, but `cmd.exe` (the "DOS prompt") doesn't. Run the command `chcp 65001`  in the DOS prompt before starting Python and it might work. Else try running it in the `idle` GUI that comes with Python or even better, use IPython.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Running chcp 65001 worked for me. Now the code works. But the print output is "Ø¹: ain". Is there a way to print Arabic letters on DOS windows?

Comment: @Naseem You need a change the settings for `cmd.exe` to use a unicode font. See e.g. [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2008/04/22/give-your-eyes-a-treat.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for your help. I was able to see the correct characters in Arabic displayed. I had to use Window's PowerShell , install Courier New font for the shell and run chcp 1256.

Comment: @Ronald is 'arabic letter' in [if 'arabic letter' in id] is a keyword? I could not find any documentation on that.

Comment: @Naseem No. The arabic code block does not only contain letters but also digits and other symbols. However, the *names* of the letters tend to start with the string *arabic letter*, which is why I use it as a way to filter out non-letters. The statement `'arabic letter' in id` only evaluates as `True` if the text 'arabic letter' can be found in the string id.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This clarifies.

Answer (score 1):

Refer to the Unicode [numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arabic_script_in_Unicode) for each character and then construct a dictionary as follows here:

```
arabic = {'alif': u'\u0623', 'baa': u'\u0628', ...} # use unicode mappings like so
```

Comment: No need to look up the names. They're part of the standard library!

Answer (score 1):

Use a simple dictionary in python to do this properly. Make sure your file is set in the following way:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

Here is code that should work for you (I added in examples of how to get out the values from your dictionary as well, since you are a beginner):

```
exampledict = {unicode(('ا').decode('utf-8')):'ALIF',unicode(('ع').decode('utf-8')):'AYN'}
keys = exampledict.keys()
values = exampledict.values()
print(keys)
print(values)
exit()
```

Output:

```
[u'\u0639', u'\u0627']
['AYN', 'ALIF']
```

Hope this helps you on your journey learning python, it is fun!

Comment: when I run this example, I get the error ' Name Error name 'unicode' not defined'. I have added the header lines as you suggested.

Comment: add the line 'import codecs', if that doesn't work, try u Instead of unicode, this may be because of issues between python 3 & 2, the example above works for python 2.7